# Flex 4 - Need some help with startup progress

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, preloader, flash-builder

Is there a way to wrap my HTTPServices into the startup progress?  Right now I have the HTTPRequest Send actions set for creationComplete on the Application (Application creationComplete="initApp()").  Is there a way to have them as part of the initial startup and progress bar?  This way all the data will be loaded when the progress bar is complete.

Comment: Did my suggestion help answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom preloader for that. I think [this tutorial](http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2008/07/06/flex-application-bootstrapping-totally-custom-preloader/) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try tying your HTTPServices call to the `preinitialize` event of the main Application.

Check out [this article](http://www.wietseveenstra.nl/blog/2007/02/understanding-the-flex-application-startup-event-order/) for more info on the Flex startup order.

Answer (score 1):

Constantiner's suggestions is correct. You should read [my tutorial on how to make a custom preloader](http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2008/07/06/flex-application-bootstrapping-totally-custom-preloader/). The focus in the tutorial is not on how to skin the preloader, but on how to include a custom time-consuming actions to take place during the preloading of the Flex application.

The tutorial includes also an updated Flex 4 sample that demonstrates where you should plug your service call.

In your particular case you need to wait for the Flex framework to load before using the **HTTPService**, because the **HTTPService**-class is part of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the HTTPRequest to a method that responds to the initialize event, like so:

```
initialize="getData()"
creationComplete="initApp()"
```

The initialize event dispatches much earlier in the application's life cycle.